# Multigraph and cheapest path

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I have a problem to solve, I need to find the cheapest path between two cities, but there are several possible path between two neighboring cities so I have a Multigraph and i can have discount between two edge . Is there an algorithm to find the cheapest path in a Multigraph?

thanks!

Comment: Dijkstra will work just fine.

Comment: Dijkstra works on a multigraph?

Comment: Sure, why not? When in doubt you can also convert to graph by removing useless edges - for edges A->B only one shortest has chance to be useful.

Comment: I modify the description of my problem because is more complex.

Comment: what is "discount" mean? can you give us some details.

Comment: I mean that each edge can have a link with the previous edge of the path, ie it is possible to apply discount to edges based on the previous edges

Comment: 1: For every multi-edge, keep the one with lowest weight. 2: Apply Dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: Looking for something similar I found this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=25FEE27EEE869D105B66D52A4CB7D9ED?doi=10.1.1.675.7229&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Best I've found so far.

Comment: someone please share a sample implementation of dijkstra for multigraph? I have started to doubt life trying to find solution for this :D ^^.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dijkstra works with Multigraphs, but you should not keep track of visited vertices, you have to examine them again because of the parallel edges. Moreover, whenever you find a self-loop you should move one without any calculations.

Answer (score 0):

For each edge select tha discounted weight for that edge and undiscounted weight for all other edges then use Dijkstra

The answer will be the minimum of all Dijkstras

This is the best I have got so far

In my version of the question cities were connected by national and state highways and to find the shortest path between two cities you could take a maximum of 1 national highway

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).